# Traffic Light Sequence

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on my "helping my 5 year old son with a traffic light sequence" (as it was so eloquently put), and I've checked multiple sources and I just cannot figure out why my code doesn't work.

Here it is:

```
</body>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<img id="light" src="Red.png">

<script>
var list= ['Green.png', 'Yellow.png', 'Red.png']; 
var i = 0;
function lightsCycle() {
    i = i + 1;
    i = i % arr.length;
    if (i == list.length) i = 0; 
    return arr[i];
    var image = document.getElementById(element).src = list[i].src;;
            light.src=list[i];
</script>

<button type = "button" onclick="lightCycle()">Next Light</button>

</html>
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work"

Comment: what's up with your closing `</body>` tag?

Comment: `lightCycle` vs `lightsCycle`

Comment: The tag was misplaced in editing it on here - it's in place on the original code, and the other errors I have no excuse for - I'm a mess. :)

Answer (score 5):

**Errors**

1. Your closing `body` tag is misplaced
2. You have a `lightsCycle` function but you are calling `lightCycle()` (missing **s**)
3. You forgot a bracket at the end of the function
4. You are using the variable `arr` that does not exist
5. You have a `return arr[i];` statement in middle of your code. The next lines of code won't be executed

Please see the following code for a simple example. I replaced the image with colors

*To get your code with images do the following :*

Replace the colors by the path to your images

Replace the `<span>` by `<img>`

Replace `document.getElementById("light").style.color = nextColor;` by `document.getElementById("light").src = nextColor;`

```js
var list = ['green', 'yellow', 'red'];
var index = 2;

function lightsCycle() {
  document.getElementById("light").style.color = list[++index % list.length];;
}
```

```html
<span id="light" style="color: red">●</span>
<button type="button" onclick="lightsCycle()">Next Light</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i = i % arr.length;
```

Should be `i % list.length;`

```
var image = document.getElementById(element).src = list[i].src;;
```

Should be `var light = document.getElementById("light").src=list[i];`

```
onclick="lightCycle()"
```

Should be `onclick="lightsCycle()"`
You need the body tag after the button.
No need for the if statement with the modulus.
`light.src=list[i];` is repetitive.
And you need a closing bracket for the function.
The return will just stop the src from changing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<img id="light" src="Red.png">

<script>
var list= ['Green.png', 'Yellow.png', 'Red.png']; 
var i = 0;
function lightsCycle() {
    i = i + 1;
    i = i % list.length;
    var light = document.getElementById("light").src = list[i];
}
</script>

<button type = "button" onclick="lightsCycle()">Next Light</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a working version, lots of errors fixed.